# Is there a way to manage multiple module version within python3.7

Tags: python

I have a requests module version 2.24.0 but I also want to install snowflake-connector-python which requires requests version 2.23.0 or lower. Is there a way to manage these two version in my project without downgrading ?

I have seen examples like below which is trying to manage within the file where a different request version is needed
 `import pkg_resources; pkg_resources.require("requests==2.23.0");`

but getting error:

```
> File "/Users/../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 791, in resolve
>     raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req) pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (requests 2.24.0
> (/Users/../Projects/../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
> Requirement.parse('requests==2.23.0'))
```

Please note: I am using virtual environment.

Comment: Use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). There is no way to have two separate versions installed in same environment.

Comment: This is happening within virtual environment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to manage two different versions of a package within the same Python environment. If snowflake-connector-python is requiring requests 2.23.0 or lower then you'll have to downgrade to requests 2.23.0 or lower in your virtual environment.

Comment: I think I will agree with you on that, as I have done extensive research with no solution. Thanks